# MySQL Replace Will Not Replace

Tags: mysql, replace

I feel like I'm loosing it here, this exact query used to work just fine but now it matches rows but won't change any of them, I've disabled safe updates in Workbench and even tried from CLI and same result, did something change in the REPLACE function that I'm not aware of?

Tried both ways just incase:

```
update MyVideos116.path set strPath = replace(strPath,'smb://STORAGESRV-VM/','smb://WMHomeStorage/')    
update MyVideos116.path set strPath = replace(strPath,'smb://STORAGESRV-VM/','smb://WMHomeStorage/') WHERE strPath LIKE '%STORAGESRV-VM%';
```

Result is the same with the exception that with the WHERE statement I get a few less results:

```
0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1258  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1247  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, sorry it was the case of the STORAGESRV-VM which in the tables is StorageSrv-VM